# Reading the File size for each blob inside a directory of a Blob Container using Azure-Storage-Blob Python

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

We have an "Azure Blob Storage" for large amounts of data in a cloud. And we have blob containers which contain several directories , and within each directory, we have several blob files of type "Block Blob" and they are '.orc' files. We need to list content of such a directory using the path of the blobs , and then get specific blob information,**most importantly the file size for each blob**. Currently, we are planning to use "azure-storage-python" for it but are currently lost in its documentation , and are confused on how to achieve our target.
[This is the link for the python library we are using :](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python)

Any help would be highly appreciated! Eagerly Waiting for a response!

Comment: You should share the code that you started to use for the community to better help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to list the file size of each blob. There is a very direct way:

```
# Create the BlobServiceClient that is used to call the Blob service for the storage account
conn_str = ' '
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=conn_str)
container_name = ' '

# List the blobs's information in the container
print("\nList blobs in the container")
container = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=container_name)
generator = container.list_blobs()
for blob in generator:
    print("\t Blob name: " + blob.name)
    print("\t Blob size: "+ str(blob.size))
```

It works in my way.

[image]

If you want to list all information of the blob, just do `print(blob)`.

Comment: ..Thank you so much for the detailed explanation..
Its quite intuitive and useful :D